# Quality get reduced when convert imageview to image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimageview, uikit

In photo editor screen , I have imageview and it has background image and on top of imageview I add elements like text (label), stickers(images) etc. , Now for the final image containing all elements added on imageview , I am getting image from below code

clipRect is rect for background image inside imageview, image is aspectfit in imageview

Below is code inside UIView extension which has function to generate image out of view.

self == uiview

```
                  let op_format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        op_format.scale = 1.0
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: clipRect!.origin, size: outputSize), format: op_format)
        let originalBound = self.bounds
        self.bounds = CGRect(origin: clipRect!.origin, size: clipRect!.size)
        var finalImage = renderer.image { ctx in
            self.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: self.bounds.origin, size: outputSize), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        self.bounds = CGRect(origin: originalBound.origin, size: originalBound.size)
```

Issue here is quality of final image quality is very poor as compared to original background image.

Comment: The issue here is that there is no presence of an `UIImgeView` object regardless of what the title suggests.

Comment: @ElTomato for more clarity added details, code is inside function of uiview extension

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the scale of your `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat` to 1. That forces the output image to @1x (non-retina). For most (all?) iOS devices, that will cause a 2X or 3X loss of resolution. Leave the scale value of the UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat at the default value.

Answer (score 0):

you can take screenshot as well

```
// Convert a uiview to uiimage
    func captureView() -> UIImage {
        // Gradually increase the number for high resolution.     
        let scale = 1.0 

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, opaque, scale)  

        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image:UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
```

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is being phased out. You should use UIGraphicsImageRenderer instead. And the comment "Gradually increase the number for high resolution" is nonsense. For most cases, you should set a value of 0, which will use the screen resolution.

Comment: Okay sir i am in learning as a junior developer I implemented the above code for taking high resolution screenshot from i ll change my function with your suggestion :) thankyou